# Rodando threads dependentes paralelamente em python

Tags: python, multithreading, websocket, stream

Estou tentando rodar 2 threads simultaneamente em meu programa em Python:

```
from threading import Thread
import manipulateData
import stream

processo1 = Thread(stream.main())
print(processo1)
processo2 = Thread(manipulateData.main())
print(processo2)

processo1.start()
processo2.start()
```

No `processo1` eu rodo alguns websockets que coletam dados de alguns sites.
No `processo2` eu manipulo esses dados para fazer algumas análises.

O problema é que quando rodo o programa ele primeiro executa o `processo1` e só inicia o `processo2` quando dou um stop no `processo1` (clico no botão stop no PyCharm).

Aliás, alguém indica algum curso ou material específico sobre multithreading e websockets?
Valeu!

Comment: Fiz um teste simples aqui e, se usar 2 funções mais simples como target da thread, paralelizou sem problema. Você menciona que o processo2 lida com dados que vêm do processo1. Como eles se comunicam entre si? Imagino que o problema seja que um esteja esperando pelo outro, mas isto está acontecendo num código que não o incluso na pergunta.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

bom você esta executando a `function` dentro da thread e não passando com parâmetro

exemplo:

```py
processo1 = Thread(target=stream.main()) # chamando a function
processo1.start()

processo1 = Thread(target=stream.main) # passando como parâmetro
processo1.start()
```